# Create a const std::vector with another const std::vector and additional values

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std

Consider a const vector `v1`

```
const std::vector<int> v1{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

I want to create a new const vector `v2` with the contents of vector `v1` with additional values like so:

```
const std::vector<int> v1{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
const std::vector<int> v2{v1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Create a temporary vector, build its contents, then use it to construct `v2`. Or, define and implement a custom iterator class that iterates over all contents of `v1` and the new values, and use the `std::vector` constructor that's a template which takes a sequence defined by a beginning and an ending iterator.

Comment: I currently have a function that combines `v1` and the additional values and returns a new vector to construct with, but I am asking if there might be  a more elegant solution for this problem

Comment: Oh, in that case your question would be off-topic for stackoverflow, and should be closed as such. "More elegant" is obviously opinion-based, by definition; and opinion-based questions would be off-topic, unfortunately.

Comment: I disagree, the "more elegant" solution should make use of the tools that the standard library offers in this context and I am not sure how to implement that without creating my own functions or classes

Comment: There's nothing in the C++ library for this.

Comment: That is my guess too, but I am not too sure about that

Comment: C++20 will have constexpr vectors

Comment: Consider using `array` instead of `vector` if that will suit your needs (those already have constexpr compatibility). The main benefit of `vector` is runtime resizeability but declaring as `const` discards that ability.

Comment: The reason I'm confident that there's nothing like this in the C++ library is because something like this can only be done in two ways. 1) A dedicated vector constructor, and I'm pretty sure there isn't one; 2) A fundamental part of C++ language's grammar and syntax that I'm pretty sure doesn't exist. There are no other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following convenience function template, `make_vector()`:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> make_vector(const std::vector<T>& v, std::initializer_list<T> l) {
   std::vector<T> u(v);
   u.insert(u.end(), l.begin(), l.end());
   return u;
}
```

It creates a temporary vector `u`, which contains the elements of the vector passed to the function and the elements of the `initializer_list`.

Note that it usually makes little sense for the convenience function to return a `const` object by value (for example, the returned object can't be moved). Therefore, the convenience function above returns a non-`const` vector instead, i.e., `std::vector<T>`. You can, however, initialize a `const` vector with this returned non-`const` vector, and it will be move initialized.

```
auto main() -> int {
   const std::vector<int> u{1, 2, 3};
   auto const v = make_vector(u, {4, 5, 6});

   for (auto elem: v)
      std::cout << elem << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: thank you for your time answering this question, I already have the problem solved exactly the way you described it, but my question is, whether there might be a more elegant solution to this problem like `const std::vector<int> v2{v1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`

Comment: @emm The other approach I can think of is to create your own type that takes a vector and an `initializer_list` at construction and provides the `begin()` and `end()` member functions.